# Add variable in %x command in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use the %x ( ) and use a variable that i've used earlier to determine a path of a file that i want to run.

essentially i want to do something like this

```
location = "/home/myhome/somefolder"
%x ("ls " + location)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works

```
%x ("ls " + location)
```

Or

```
%x ("ls #{location}")
```

Comment: Thanks, I realize the error in my way was not using the right escape character in the string. i needed to use // to denote a single slash.

Answer (score 1):

The example you provided works fine but you should probably use `Shellwords` to escape any variables e.g.

```
require 'shellwords'

location = '~/My folder with spaces in the name'

%x("ls #{Shellwords::escape(location)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm using ruby 2 and none of the above worked for me. so i wound up using something like

`eval "%x(ls #{location})"`